# CSS animation jumps

Tags: html, css, animation

Sorry, I'm new to css animations so maybe it's studpid ;) So I got a overlay div I want to animate from top to bottom (fixed at top) and then scale down (fixed at the bottom) but the animations jumps some sequences. I really don't know why. here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mzd7rqqL/

I think you can see what I try to achieve!

**CSS**

```
  .overlay {
    background: #00b2c0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-animation: infinite 2s;
    animation: infinite 2s;

    .off {
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      animation: none !important;
      -webkit-animation: none !important;
    }
  }

  @keyframes rolldown {
    0% {transform: scaleY(0); transform-origin: left top;}
    50% { transform: scaleY(1); }
    100% {transform: scaleY(0); transform-origin: left bottom;}
  }

  .rolldown {
    -webkit-animation-name: rolldown;
    animation-name: rolldown;
  }
```

HTML

```
<div class="overlay rolldown"></div>
```

thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you mean the flickering effect?

Comment: yes if you want to call it like that. the div should be "fixed" to the top for the first 50% to scale from top to down and then it should be "fixed" at the bottom and scale down. I hope you understand me? ;) but in some seconds it "jumps" from top/bottom. don't know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> ...the div should be "fixed" to the top for the first 50% to scale from top to down and then it should be "fixed" at the bottom and scale down...

To solve this, I've added **two steps** keyframes: `rolldown1` and `rolldown2`. First, it will animate top to down, wait 3 seconds and then animate to collapse and disappear.

---

## Solution:

```css
.overlay {
  background: #00b2c0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes rolldown1 {
  0%   {
    -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
            transform-origin: left top;
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
            transform: scaleY(0);
  }
  
  100% {
    -webkit-transform-origin: left top;
            transform-origin: left top;
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
            transform: scaleY(1);
  }
}

@keyframes rolldown2 {
  0%   {
    -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
            transform-origin: left bottom;
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
            transform: scaleY(1);
  }
  
  50%   {
    -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
            transform-origin: left bottom;
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.5);
            transform: scaleY(0.5);    
  }
  
  100% { 
    -webkit-transform-origin: left bottom;
            transform-origin: left bottom;
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
            transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}

.rolldown {
  /* here, it will wait for 3 seconds before collapsing */

  -webkit-animation: 
    rolldown1 1s linear 0s 1 normal forwards,
    rolldown2 1s linear 3s 1 normal forwards
  ;

  animation: 
    rolldown1 1s linear 0s 1 normal forwards,
    rolldown2 1s linear 3s 1 normal forwards
  ;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay rolldown"></div>
```

Comment: thank you but now its not fixed to the bottom at 50%?

Comment: no, sorry. but I found another that achieves my wishes: https://jsfiddle.net/mh9j763r/1/

Comment: @FNGR actually, i've done the same thing. can you run my snippet again please? in your solution, it scales 2x which is not good. check mine, it scales to 1x which might be correct.

Comment: oooouh sorry, I didn't saw your solution right because of the delay :D sorry! yes, looks great!

Comment: @FNGR thank you. i've kind of improved it again. check it here please: https://jsfiddle.net/inancgumus/4gmnz0d3/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS has error, try the following CSS

```
.overlay {
    background: #00b2c0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-animation: infinite 2s;
    animation: infinite 2s;
}
.off {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    animation: none !important;
    -webkit-animation: none !important;
}
 @keyframes rolldown {
 0% {
 transform: scaleY(0);
 transform-origin: left top;
 }
 50% 
 {
 transform: scaleY(1);
 }
 100% {
 transform: scaleY(0);
 transform-origin: left bottom;
}
}
.rolldown {
    -webkit-animation-name: rolldown;
    animation-name: rolldown;
}
```

Comment: looks like the same for me? just in CSS intead of SCSS... but the "jumping" or "flickering" effect is still there?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should set height in 50% of "rolldown", try this:

```
  .overlay {
background: #00b2c0;
position: absolute;
top: 0; left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 1;
-webkit-animation: infinite 2s;
animation: infinite 2s;
```

}

```
@keyframes rolldown {
0% {transform: scaleY(0); transform-origin: left top;}
50% { transform: scaleY(1); height: 10%; }
100% {transform: scaleY(0); transform-origin: left bottom; }
```

}

Comment: thanks for your answer but same effect and now it's additionally "lagging".

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J7Aw7/371/)

```
.container{
    background:#00b2c0;
    height:1000px;
    -webkit-animation: expand 5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes expand{
    0%{height:0px}
    100%{height:1000px}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so, i can't got it to work with scale but I could get it working with translate!

https://jsfiddle.net/mh9j763r/1/

```
  .overlay {
    background: #00b2c0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -100%; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-animation: infinite 2s;
    animation: infinite 2s;
  }

  @keyframes rolldown {
    0% {transform: translateY(0);}
    50% { transform: translateY(100%);}
    100% { transform: translateY(200%);}
  }

  .rolldown {
    -webkit-animation-name: rolldown;
    animation-name: rolldown;
  }
```